# e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package

Tags: wix, .net-6.0, .net-4.8, .net-standard-2.0

Currently In my Solution it is containing `.net Framework 4.8` , `.net Standard` and `net 6` assemblies .

during installing the particular artifacts (.exe) of the solution, I can't  install it and getting the exception as

```
Error 1001. Unable to get installer types in the <file>\service.exe assembly.--> Unable to loadone or more request types.
```

for other .net framework and .net standard the wix setup are like this

```
<Component Id="__Device_dll" Guid="{9C75189F-BE83-4227-A798-F00C76F27CE6}">
   <File Id="__Device_dll" Name="Device.dll" KeyPath="yes"  Assembly=".net" AssemblyManifest="_Device_dll" AssemblyApplication="Device_dll" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\Device.dll" />
</Component>
```

but for .net 6

```
<Component Id="Process_Executor_exe" Guid="{0D8D84F1-FFC5-28F6-F1D7-8620DA17313B}">
  <File Id="Process_Executor_exe" Name="SProcess.Executor.exe" Source="$(var.SimulationSourceDir)\Process.Executor.exe" />
</Component>
```

Is something I am missing in wix set up ,because the application rus fine in visual studio , during installation only `Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package` these error logs are comming.